# Creating multiple lists or a dictionary to save PDF object using pyPDF2?

Tags: python, for-loop, pdf, pypdf

I have multiple PDF files, from which I need to extract text. I am using pyPDF2 package for extracting text from each of the PDF file. I need to save each extraction into new list variable or in a dictionary, so I could access them later for stigmatization process

I have used following code so far, I am confused with creating multiple list variables using `for` loop in my code block

```
new1=[]
new2=[]
for i in range(len(d[extension[4]])):
    pdfFileObj= open(mydir+'\\'+d[extension[4]][i],'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    new1.append(pdfFileObj)
    new2.append(pdfReader)

PDFfile0 =[]
PDFfile1 =[]
PDFfile2 =[]
PDFfile3 =[]
PDFfile4 =[]

for j in range(5):
    for i in range(new2[j].numPages):
       pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
       text = pageObj.extractText()
       PDFfile+str(j).append(text)  # here i am facing problem
```

where `d(extension[4])` is pdf.

I need to save each result in a new PDFfilen...list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a list-of-lists. In other words, something along these lines:

```
new1=[]
new2=[]
for i in range(len(d[extension[4]])):
    pdfFileObj= open(mydir+'\\'+d[extension[4]][i],'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    new1.append(pdfFileObj)
    new2.append(pdfReader)

NUM_LISTS = 5
PDFfiles = [[] for _ in range(NUM_LISTS)]

for j in range(NUM_LISTS):
    for i in range(new2[j].numPages):
       pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
       text = pageObj.extractText()
       PDFfiles[j].append(text)  # Use index to select sublist.
```

Comment: ved_null_: Note: Use of the constant `NUM_LISTS` should probably be replaced with regular variable. i.e. `num_list = len(new2)`. Doing this would make it more data-driven and flexible.